# Bitbucket Jdk Version Mismatch Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, bitbucket

I am developing my application on Java version 1.8 and since my repository is on bitbucket, it is picking up the default configuration of Java 11.
Everything is working fine but when I am writing **Integration Tests** using Junit Mockito framework I am getting exception on bitbucket while executing the pipeline. Locally all tests are working fine.

Bitbucket by default is picking the latest version on sonar plugin which is 3.9 and because of that I am getting this exception

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project xyz: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I have tried following changes but nothing happened

```
1) Changed image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 To image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 in bitbucket-pipeline.yml file.
2) Added jacoco 0.7.9 version (Java 8 compatible) in pom file
3) Added sonar-maven-plugin version 3.6 (tried to downgrade it to be compatible with Java 8) in pom file
```

Can someone guide what is missing and what can be the issue. Also if I want to change the default bitucket docker image configuration how can I do that?

My bitbucket-pipeline.yml file

```
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11   #image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
clone
....
definitions
  caches
     sonar: ....
  steps
  ...
  ...
  script:
     cd impl
     mvn -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar
```

My Integration Test File

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CountryControllerTest{
   @Autowired public MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Test
   public void getCountryListTest() throws Exception {
      mockMvc
       .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/countries"))
       .andDo(print())
       .andExpect(status().isOk())
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.length()").value(2))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data[0].name").value("USA"))
       .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE));
   }
}
```

The Error is only occurring on bitbucket pipeline and not in local development

```
[ERROR] getCountryListTest(com.xyz.controller.CountryControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyTokenFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7675d305' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#12345': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#12345' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#12345': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#12345': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Java SE 17. Java SE 8 is slowly being discontinued.

Or else try using GitHub or GitLab. that should do the trick.

there is also a free app called ci circle in Github.

it is very easy once you install it.it's free for the bonus.

it can build your apps automatically every time you commit.

Comment: Moving to Java 11 solved the issue